# `supportsSecureCoding` crashes when using Optimize for Speed option

Tags: swift, nssecurecoding

I'm having trouble creating classes that uses NSSecureCoding and its subclasses.

```
class ClassA: NSObject, NSSecureCoding {
    public static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { return true }
}

class ClassB: ClassA {
    public static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { return true } // "Cannot override static var"
}
```

I'm supposed to call this since the documentation in NSObject.h says,

> This property must return YES on all classes that allow secure coding. Subclasses of classes that adopt NSSecureCoding and override initWithCoder: must also override this method and return YES.
>       // The Secure Coding Guide should be consulted when writing methods that decode data.

Objective-C:

```
@property (class, readonly) BOOL supportsSecureCoding;
```

Swift:

```
public static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { get }
```

I am using Xcode 10.0, tried on both Swift 4.0 and Swift 4.2.
How are people getting around this? Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:
When using `public class var supportsSecureCoding`, it compiles but it crashes at runtime when Optimize for Speed is used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems the current optimizer of Swift suppresses to generate the overridden getter method when its definition is the same as its superclass. What a clever optimizer!?

This sort of hack would suppress such too strong optimization.

```
class ClassB: ClassA {

    //...

    static private var secureCoding = true
    override public class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { return secureCoding }

}
```

`static private let` does not have the same effect. So, when the Swift optimizer being more clever, the code above may not work. Better send a bug report soon.

---

Seems the Swift optimizer is already clever enough and the workaround above may not work. 
(See Martin R's comment.)

You may need to remove `private`.

```
class ClassB: ClassA {

    //...

    static var secureCoding = true
    override public class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { return secureCoding }

}
```

Comment: I agree that it looks like a bug. But even with your workaround it still crashes if optimized. Here is my quick and dirty test code: https://gist.github.com/martinr448/03aa3f425a636d469769020dbe3953b5.

Comment: @MartinR, Thanks, I tested my code in an iOS project, but it seems the optimizer is already clever enough for a small project. Maybe you need to remove `private`.

Comment: Indeed, that makes it work (in a macOS command line project)!

Comment: Fun variant: `override public class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { return Int.random(in: 1...1) > 0 }`

Comment: @OOPer @MartinR Using `static private var secureCoding = true` was still crashing but `static var secureCoding = true` made it work. Thank you! What a weird compiler bug :D

Answer (score 6):

`static` in a class declaration is an alias for `final class`, i.e. a type method
which cannot be overridden in a subclass. What you want is a `class`  method

```
public class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { return true }
```

which can be overridden in the subclass with

```
override public class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { return true }
```

Comment: You might also need to add `@objc` to expose the method to the Objective-C runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but I get a crash at runtime (hence I started looking into this issue) ```*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Class 'MyModel' has a superclass that supports secure coding, but 'MyModel' overrides -initWithCoder: and does not override +supportsSecureCoding. The class must implement +supportsSecureCoding and return YES to verify that its implementation of -initWithCoder: is secure coding compliant.'`` In the subclass, I do have `@objc override public class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { return true }`

Comment: @Gomfucius: It works in my simple test. Can you post a minimal self-contained example which leads to the crash?

Comment: can you try setting the Swift optimization level to "Optimize for Speed" and trying again? I think that's causing the issue.

Comment: @Gomfucius: Yes, same here. – It works in Debug configuration, but crashes in the Release configuration. Unfortunately, I have no idea why that happens.

Answer (score 1):

I could not get any of the above answers to work. This is definitely a bug on Apple's side they will need to address so make sure you send it in the Feedback system. I even added the @objc without luck.

The Swift 5.3 compiler now gives a deprecation message for NSKeyedArchiver for initializations that don't specify secure coding.. but apparently the language doesn't allow for overriding this in subclasses.

When I don't override the variable I get:
Error: Class 'Subclass' has a superclass that supports secure coding, but 'Subclass' overrides -initWithCoder: and does not override +supportsSecureCoding. The class must implement +supportsSecureCoding and return YES to verify that its implementation of -initWithCoder: is secure coding compliant. (NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException)

When I do override the variable I get: "Cannot override a static variable"

CONDITIONAL WORKAROUND:

This workaround worked for me, as I have a super type that is sort of abstract in that it is never used without a subtype. If you have a similar setup, this should work for you:

```
public class Supertype: NSObject, NSCoding {
     ...

}
```

Subtype:

```
public class SubType: Supertype, NSSecureCoding {

     public static var supportsSecureCoding = true
     ...
}
```

This way the var is at least in  all subtypes that I use.

If you instantiate and work with Supertype directly, this will not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Fix that worked for me

```
private static var secureCodingWorkaround = true
@objc override public class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { return secureCodingWorkaround }
```

Comment: this fix did not work for me. The compiler is still not happy 'Cannot override mutable property with read-only property 'supportsSecureCoding''
XCode15, Swift5

Comment: And do you still have such issue? Probably with Xcode15 there is no need in such workaround

Comment: indeed I did declare in main class 'class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool {true}' rather than 'static var supportsSecureCoding = true' and in subclasses 'override class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool {true}'