# NSSecureCoding how to override the required supportsSecureCoding in a subclass

Tags: ios, swift, nssecurecoding

I'm trying to resolve this runtime error on an iOS project using swift 5

> The class must implement +supportsSecureCoding and return YES to verify that its implementation of -initWithCoder: is secure coding compliant." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Class 'Divinstructor.ResultDE' has a superclass that supports secure coding, but 'Divinstructor.ResultDE' overrides -initWithCoder: and does not override +supportsSecureCoding. The class must implement +supportsSecureCoding and return YES to verify that its implementation of -initWithCoder: is secure coding compliant.}

However I have not found a way to overcome this error as try to follow the error instruction result in a compilation error that I still fail to solve

I'm updating my application to NSSecureCoding.
NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with:) is deprecated starting iOS12 and have to be replaced by
NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: ,from: ) which indeed turn in having to move away from NSCoding for NSSecureCoding.

It works for my main class (Result) that I modify to conform to NSSecureCoding.
One of the required stuff is to add in the class that conforms to NSSecureCoding

```
static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true
```

However I'm facing an issue at runtime (see above) for a class (ResultDE) that is inherit from my class (Result).

The error message says that "ResultDE' has a superclass that supports secure coding, but 'Divinstructor.ResultDE' overrides -initWithCoder: and does not override +supportsSecureCoding."

However I have tried many options to override supportsSecureCoding but without any success.

```
override public static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool= true
```

The obvious one above also produce the compilation error "Cannot override with a stored property 'supportsSecureCoding'"
All my attempts result in a compilation error.
"Cannot override with a stored property 'supportsSecureCoding'"

So is anybody as an idea of how to override supportsSecureCoding in a subclass ?

I tried to remove static for the supportsSecureCoding in the man class (making it non conform to protocol) and I still have the "Cannot override with a stored property 'supportsSecureCoding'" compilation error.

here is a short code that reproduce the compilation error

```
import Foundation

class Result : NSObject, NSSecureCoding {


    static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true

    var name: String = "-"

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init()
        name = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
    }
    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
    }



    class ResultDE: Result {
        override static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true

        required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init()
            name = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
        }
        override func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
            coder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`supportsSecureCoding\` crashes when using Optimize for Speed option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52544461/supportssecurecoding-crashes-when-using-optimize-for-speed-option)

Comment: Specifically, [Martin R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52544617/169394) is the pertinent one: `static var`s can't be overridden by subclasses, but `class var`s can. If you make it a `class var`, you'll be able to override it in `ResultDE`.

Comment: removing the static for the var: declaring it var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true in Result et on override var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true will result in the same error 'Cannot override with a stored property 'supportsSecureCoding'.
You can try based on the simple code I shared.
You'll got an additional error 'Type 'Result' does not conform to protocol 'NSSecureCoding' as the NSSecureCoding force tou use static for supportsSecureCoding
My parent class needs NSSecureCoding I cannot move to NSCoding for it.

Comment: @StephaneGasparini Note that the suggestion is **not** to just drop `static` to turn `static var supportsSecureCoding = true` into `var supportsSecureCoding = true`, but to _replace_ `static` with `class` into `class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { true }` (because `static` means "don't allow overriding" and `class` means "allow overriding"). In your subclass, you then use `override class var`, **not** `override var`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Itai Ferber here is the way to do it.

```
static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true
```

need to be replaced by

```
class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool {true}
```

class then can be overridden in sub-classes.

Here code example with the fixes.

```
import Foundation

class Result : NSObject, NSSecureCoding {


    public class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool {true}

    var name: String = "-"

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init()
        name = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
    }
    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
    }



    class ResultDE: Result {
        override public class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool {true} 

        required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init()
            name = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
        }
        override func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
            coder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Itai Ferber simply pointed out the specific answer from the duplicate I linked. Your question should be closed as a duplicate of that other question instead of getting more and more answers that were already provided in that other question.

Comment: Nice solution with the class var! Only complaint on your code is not calling super to encode its data (see my solution).

Comment: @ David H The sample was there to highlight the issue of 'static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true' found in apple doc that doesn't allow overriding. The encode is done elsewhere in my application.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: updated code to use Stephane Gasparini `supportsSecureCoding`.

```
class Result : NSObject, NSSecureCoding {
   class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { true }

    var name: String = "-"

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init()
        name = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
    }
    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
    }
}


class ResultDE: Result {
    override class var supportsSecureCoding: Bool { true }

    var title: String = "-"

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)

        name = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "title") as! String
    }
    override func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        super.encode(with: coder)

        coder.encode(name, forKey: "title")
    }
}
```

I also added this code which generates a warning, since both classes do implement it"

```
    let r = Result()
    let r1 = ResultDE()

    if let x = r as? NSSecureCoding {
        print("AHA")
    }
    if let x = r1 as? NSSecureCoding {
        print("AHA")
    }
```

Please note that the subclass calls super for both encode and decode.

Apple is doing something very strange in insuring that the actual class (and not a subclass) is returning `supportsSecureCoding` (IMHO). What sense does it make for the subclass and the superclass to have different values? If the superclass hasn't provided `supportsSecureCoding`, then the subclass can provide the var. If the superclass has defined it as `false` (and why would they), and the subclass returns `true`, OK that makes sense.

Another oddity - when I ask the runtime if the both classes implement secure coding, the compiler said `true`, but the runtime failed. Bizarre.

Comment: removing 'static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool = true' removes the issue but ResultDE does not conform then to NSSecureCoding and the override the static var NSSecureCoding from its parent class vanished.
However in order to save those objects (serializing) and to restore it (deserializing) using NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass,from) this API required that the object you save and restore to conform to NSSecureCoding. ⇒ no error at compilation only at runtime:
'This decoder will only decode classes that adopt NSSecureCoding. Class 'ResultDE' does not adopt it.'

Comment: If I say it works this is because it has been tested on the real app using secure coding.